# User Agent Node JS

Tags: node.js, referrer-policy

I am trying to redirect all requests coming into my node js server and set their refer to null before redirecting.

It it possible to set all incoming requests User Agent Refer to NULL before redirecting?

req.query.refer = NULL?

Comment: are you redirecting client or server side?

Comment: Server side redirect

Comment: Are you using express js ?

Comment: Yes, using express.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using express, you add a middleware function that executes for each and every incoming request as shown below.

```
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser()); 


    //This is where you set the middlewear to set referer to null.

    app.use(setRefererToNull); 
    function setRefererToNull(req, res, next) {
        req.headers.referer = null;
        next();
    }
    // End of middlewear 

    app.use('/', indexRouter);
    app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

Note that this middlewear function "**setRefererToNull**" needs to be set before setting up any other route in your app.js file

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the Referrer-Policy header to no-referrer. This tells the browser to omit the Referer header entirely.

You do this in express using

```
res.set("Referrer-Policy", "no-referrer");
```

More info on the Referrer-Policy header [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Express, you can try https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet:

```
// Sets "Referrer-Policy: no-referrer"
app.use(
 helmet({
  referrerPolicy: {
   policy: "no-referrer",
  },
 })
);
```

Instead of set Referrer to null, it's tell browser not send Referrer.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using express then,

this is how you can set headers:

res.set({
  'User-Agent': null
})
or

res.header('User-Agent', null)
and then call the

res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/some url');
Finally, something like that should work:

```
router.get('/ren', function(req, res) {


    res.header('User-Agent', null);

    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/some url');
});
```

Comment: This didn't remove the refer from the request. It didn't set it as null like I was hoping