# Remove Referer Node JS

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, firefox, chromium

I am currently trying to set all refer to NULL or remove them completely before I redirect the user.

I have middleware set up where I thought was setting everything to null:

```
app.use(setRefererToNull); 

function setRefererToNull(req, res) {
    req.headers.referer = null;
    return res.redirect(someURL);
}
```

But this is not always removing the refer and URL's are still being sent.

Is there another/better solution;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [User Agent Node JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002649/user-agent-node-js)

Comment: Unfortunately no :/

Comment: You're setting the _request's_ referrers to null, which does nothing because you already received them. Then you redirect a user using a normal redirect response, and _that redirect_ will still have a referrer in it because you did nothing to prevent that. You probably want to set a header for that redirect that sets a `Referrer-Policy` value `no-referrer`.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that your Chromium tag is enabled, why not use standard chromium source?

```
 chrome.privacy.websites.referrersEnabled.set({value:false});
```

Taken from this library...

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/privacy

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue and wanted to pass on what worked for me. Here is how I was able to hide the referring URL:

```
...
res.set('Referrer-Policy', 'no-referrer'); //hide referrer
res.redirect(302, redirect_url);
```

Which, I admit, is precisely what @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans suggested in his comment.